# Applying a function on pandas dataframe to perform a sentiment analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the function below that performs a sentiment analysis in phrase and returns a tuple `(sentiment, % NB classifier)`, like `(sadness, 0.78)`

I want to apply this function on a pandas dataframe `df.Message` to analyse it and then create 2 another columns `df.Sentiment` , `df.Prob`

The code is below:

```
def avalia(teste):
    testeStemming = []
    stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
    for (palavras_treinamento) in teste.split():
        comStem = [p for p in palavras_treinamento.split()]
        testeStemming.append(str(stemmer.stem(comStem[0])))

    novo = extrator_palavras(testeStemming)
    distribuicao = classificador.prob_classify(novo)
    classe_array = [(classe, (distribuicao.prob(classe))) for classe in distribuicao.samples()]
    inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in classe_array]
    max_key = max(inverse)[1]
    for each in classe_array:
       if each[0] == max_key:
           a=each[0] # returns the sentiment
           b=each[1] # returns the probability
           #print(each)
           return a, b
```

example on a single string:

```
avalia('i am sad today!')
(sadness, 0.98)
```

Now i have a dataframe with 13k rows and one column: Message.
I can apply my function to a dataframe column and get a pandas.series like:

```
0       (surpresa, 0.27992165905522154)
1            (medo, 0.5632686358414051)
2        (surpresa, 0.2799216590552195)
3         (alegria, 0.5429940754962914)
```

I want to use these info´s to create 2 new columns in the same dataframe, like below.

```
    Message    Sentiment      Probability
0   I am sad    surpresa        0.2799
1   I am happy  medo            0.56
```

I cant get this last part done. Any help please?

Comment: What's the structure of your dataframe?

Comment: single column [Message] that contains a string like 'today i bought a car'..theres 13k rows.

Comment: i updated the code as you suggest, just need now the final part, add the results to new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning both values at the end of the function, and saving them into separate columns with an `apply()`:

```
def avalia(teste):
    testeStemming = []
    stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
    for (palavras_treinamento) in teste.split():
        comStem = [p for p in palavras_treinamento.split()]
        testeStemming.append(str(stemmer.stem(comStem[0])))

    novo = extrator_palavras(testeStemming)
    distribuicao = classificador.prob_classify(novo)
    classe_array = [(classe, (distribuicao.prob(classe))) for classe in distribuicao.samples()]
    inverse = [(value, key) for key, value in classe_array]
    max_key = max(inverse)[1]
    for each in classe_array:
       if each[0] == max_key:
           a=each[0] # returns the sentiment
           b=each[1] # returns the probability
    return a, b

df.Sentiment, df.Prob = df.Message.apply(avalia)
```

Comment: i tried, but got this error msg: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)